# How to get not validated text from currently being edited TextInput in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

Basically I need an event that will fire each time, when text in my custom TextInput is being edited.
Modifying insert_text works only when user type something, but not when he delete symbols.
So I might try to compare text before and while editing. Though not sure that it's best way.
Soo.. is there a way to get not validated text from currently being edited TextInput?

Answer (score 1):

Use the on_text method to get the text from the TextInput whenever it changes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comment, but still that got some time to find out the right syntax since no kv examples in official manuals.

in kv:

```
CustomInput:
    text 'somesymbols'
    on_text: self.currenttext(self.text)
```

in py:

```
CustomInput(TextInput):
    def currenttext(instance, value):
        print(value)
```